# bs4 usable to get data inside <span> tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, ip

i'm trying to get my location using webscraping. So i decided to use nordvpn(the sponsors XD) website to find my location. I opened dev tools and found the part where the location is listed has class = `js-ipdata-location` inside span tab.

The problem is when i parse it, I'm just getting the span tag as the output. And `...` as text between the tags.

here is my code -

```
ip_req = requests.get('https://nordvpn.com/what-is-my-ip/', headers = header)

bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(ip_req.text, 'lxml')
loc = bs_obj.find('span', class_ = 'js-ipdata-location')

print(loc)
```

i get the output as - `<span class="js-ipdata-location">…</span>`. I need the text between the tags, which in this case is not visible.

i even tried doing `print(loc.text)` but i just get `...` as output.

Pls help me find my location.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded dynamically from external URL. You can use this script to print data:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://nordvpn.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_user_info_data'
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data['city'], data['region'], data['country'])
```

Prints (in my case):

```
Bratislava Bratislava Slovakia
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can explain how you solved this?? Like im sure `.json()` wont work with every website out there. It will be helpful for me to solve future problems

Comment: also can you tell how you could find that url?

Comment: @default-303 I opened Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab and observed, where the page was making requests. One of the URLs was this Json call, which contains the necessary data.